# Xpath get element value when neighbor attribute value matches

Tags: xpath

I have an XML as follows:

```
<prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Approved</prop>
<prop type="x-Internal project number:SingleString">O-74205</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Services</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Raman</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Support</prop>
```

and I would like to get the element value of "***prop type="x-Internal project number:SingleString"***" when "***prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist" == Raman***".

My Xpath is the following:

```
//prop[@type = "x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist" and text() = "Raman"]
```

In my XML, the Xpath should return only O-74025.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [parent::node()](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) reference in your expression:
`//prop[@type = "x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist" and text() = "Raman"]/parent::node()/prop[@type = "x-Internal project number:SingleString"]/text()`

Answer (score 2):

Like this :

## Sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<x>
<prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Approved</prop>
<prop type="x-Internal project number:SingleString">O-74205</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Services</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Raman</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Support</prop>
</x>
<x>
<prop type="x-ConfirmationLevel">Approved</prop>
<prop type="x-Internal project number:SingleString">O-74205</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Services</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Foobar</prop>
<prop type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist">Support</prop>
</x>
</root>
```

## Code:

```
xmllint --xpath '
    //prop[@type="x-Product Line:MultiplePicklist" and \
    text()="Raman"]/../prop[@type="x-Internal project number:SingleString"]/text()
' file.xml
```

### Output:

```
O-74205
```